# Puppeteer get request redirects

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

Is there any way to use `puppeteer` to get the redirects with the response body (if there are any) of the request?

I implemented the following code but I can't find a way to get the redirects...

```
const page = await browser.newPage()

page.on('request', (data) => console.log(data));    

await page.on('response', response => {
    const url = response.url();
    response.buffer()
    .then (
        buffer => {
            bufferString = buffer.toString();         
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error)
        }
    )
})

await page.goto('https://www.ford.com', {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just check `response.status()` in your `response` handler - it will be 3xx for redirects:

```
page.on('response', response => {
  const status = response.status()
  if ((status >= 300) && (status <= 399)) {
    console.log('Redirect from', response.url(), 'to', response.headers()['location'])
  }
})
```

(Redirects don't usually have anything interesting in the response body, so you don't probably want to call `response.buffer()` for them.)

Comment: This actually returns the correct response status code including 301 and 302 redirects. Unlike for example: ```const response = await page.goto('https://example.com'); console.log(response.status());```

Answer (score 5):

This should work for every type of redirection: server-side and client-side (meta-refresh, JS, etc)

```
const page = await browser.newPage()

const redirects = [];

const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
await client.send('Network.enable');
await client.on('Network.requestWillBeSent', (e) => {
    if (e.type !== "Document") {
        return;
    }
    redirects.push(e.documentURL);
});

await page.goto('https://www.ford.com');
await page.waitForNavigation();

console.log(redirects);
```

Something like that.

Comment: nice for catch the client side ones

Comment: do you know anyway to get also response code for those requests in `Network.requestWillBeSent`, thanks

Answer (score 2):

This one looks also useful, https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/4625#issuecomment-506146528

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async() => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  const response = await page.goto('https://www.zoho.com/sa/invoice/tour/time-tracking/');
  for (const r of response.request().redirectChain())
    console.log(r.method() + ' ' + r.response().status() + ' ' + r.url());
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the response url, because in the case of a redirect, multiple URLs could be called and I think only the first one is a 301.

Note that `expect` in my code is from the `chai` library, but that's optional, assertion could be done with something else.

```
const webpage = await browser.newPage();
webpage.once('response', response => {
  if (response.url() === 'https://www.ford.com') {
    expect(response.status()).equals(301);
  }
})
await webpage.goto('https://www.ford.com');
```