# Using Puppeteer, how to get the final redirect URI without having to actually click the link and load the page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect, web-crawler, puppeteer

**TLDR; Is it possible to get the redirect URI on a clickable link that uses a JS function and location.href() or window.open() to open a new page in JS and/or Puppeteer without having to actually click the link?**

[ edit ]
Found this [Puppeteer get request redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48986851/puppeteer-get-request-redirects) while posting this question but it requires me to first "click" the link and examine the Response header, and I'm trying to get the value WITHOUT a click, which I think should be possible...

I'm building a site crawler using Puppeteer and I am doing it by actually "clicking" (simulated) each link on a page instead of just scanning the page for a.href tags and getting the indicated URIs.

I am using recursion of course and async/await and am rather new to this programming paradigm, but I seem to be making good progress.  Here is my main function that is called on each page that is returned during a "click"...

```
async function crawl(page) {

    const url = await page.url();

    // kick out already processed pages
    if (crawled_pages.has(url)) {
        CURRENT_DEPTH--;
        return false;
    }

    // scrape all rendered <a> links off page
    let page_alinks = await page.$$("a");

    // kick out of recursion if we dont find any links on the page...
    if (page_alinks.length === 0) return false;

    console.log("[ " + url + " ] links found: " + page_alinks.length);

    // var data = await page.$eval('a[href|="data:text"]', el => el.href);
    crawled_pages.set(url, page);

    // now add each of the links to a mapped collection using the concatted text and link 
    // values as the key and the link node as the value
    for (let click_node of page_alinks) {

        let href_value = await (await click_node.getProperty('href')).jsonValue();
        let text_value = await (await click_node.getProperty('text')).jsonValue();

        let redir_value = "";
        request({url: href_value, followRedirect: false}, function (err, res, body) {
            redir_value = res.headers.location;
        });

        if (debug) {
            console.log("text = " + text_value);
            console.log("href = " + href_value);
            console.log("redir= " + redir_value);
        }

        // track how deep into the recurse are we
        click_node.depth = CURRENT_DEPTH + 1;
        click_node.redir = redir_value;

        if (qued_clickable_links.store_link(text_value, href_value, click_node)) {
            if (debug) console.log("storg link [ " + text_value + "`" + href_value + " ]");
        } else {
            if (debug) console.log("rejecting link [ " + text_value + "`" + href_value + " ]");
        }
    }

    // loop the clickable links
    let clicknode = null, next_page = null;
    while ((clicknode = qued_clickable_links.pop()) === true) {
        (async () => {
            const newPagePromise = getNewPageWhenLoaded();
            await clicknode.click({delay: 1000});
            next_page = await newPagePromise;
        })();
        next_page.depth = CURRENT_DEPTH + 1;
        CURRENT_DEPTH++;
        let rv = await crawl(next_page);
    }

    CURRENT_DEPTH--;
    return true;
};
```

I've learned through experience building other non-Puppeteer based crawlers that redirected links are an issue, as you have to track each clickable link with both the initial href URI value and the final URI, and since you don't want to repeat any crawls, you should know these values BEFORE submitting them to the qued_clickable_links Map().

So using this code block will give me the redirected URI *but only on non-Javascript based href values, not on every clickable link on a page*...

```
const request = require('request');
 let redir_value = "";
        request({url: href_value, followRedirect: false}, function (err, res, body) {
            redir_value = res.headers.location;
        });
```

So for example, for one of the links on `https://krksol-miraclebust.com` at the bottom, the given value the link with `text=TERMS & CONDITIONS` is `href=javascript:void(0)` Putting these values into the above function as `href_value` just gives me an error!  That makes that function relatively worthless for what I am trying to achieve.

The whole point of this is to crawl a site thru clicking links and not just scanning the page, so I need a redirect function that understands this and gives me the value *as if I clicked the link*

Comment: My two ideas are 1. Capture the URL and ping it outside of the context of Puppeteer and inspect the headers there. You can do this in a Node environment with axios. 2. Copy the initial href value, pass it back to the Node runtime, then open the url in a new instance of a pptr browser, and record where it goes.

Comment: hmmm so how resource intensive is the axios method?  does it actually fire up a browser and render the page and scrape the header?  as far as the second, that is of course the brute force way to do it but i am really looking for, if it even exists, a way to get that value without doing the full-on render on the initial uri.  ALSO, so like your still thinking i actually HAVE a href!  thats the whole point of this...these "links" have void() href values and are rendered only by a click event :)

Comment: "these "links" have void() href values and are rendered only by a click event" - so you need to click them, or crawl the JS on that page... sounds very difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid it's one of those cases that you need to handle in a special way to build a real site crawler. I think there'll be more cases like this so your implementation should be, I'd say, more sophisticated. Generally, it's a big topic but I want you to give some insights.

There could be several different types of links and redirections on the website. Some of them are:

- links to another website
- links to another page of your website
- links to download a file
- links to send an email
- links to an anchor located on the same page
- links to an anchor located on another page

Probably I missed some, for sure I didn't mention the redirections made by executing JS function as this one that you struggle with (`href="javascript:void(0);"`)

Therefore, I recommend keeping all links as objects of a structured class rather than just a collection of links. Actually I think you do that, at least this method `qued_clickable_links.store_link()` suggests so. However, looking at the arguments that the method accepts I think it might not be enough. The class should contain information like:

- whether it's redirection URL or not
- if it contains a full path or just relative one
- does it open in the new window/tab

Only this way you can manage all of the types and problems that you will meet on your way.

But coming back to the question of getting a link without clicking it in this particular case - I'm pretty sure the only reasonable solution would be parsing `onclick` function to extract the first argument of it which means the URL of the resource to be loaded. I'm good enough in parsing strings, so I won't provide you any good implementation. You can get the string of `onclick` function this way:

```
var selector = 'body > div:nth-child(3) > div.footer__block.footer-menu > div:nth-child(3) > a';
$(selector)[0].onclick.toString();
```

I hope I helped.

Comment: , YES!  Thank you very much for your insights and I agree, links are far more then just a url...currently im storing the full elementHandle object, although im constantly battling with that as well as ive yet to find a clean, easy to understand way to id those objects so i can look at them in my debugger and figure out what is what...so `$(selector)[0].onclick.toString();` will do the trick huh?  it seems too easy lol but im marking your answer as correct no matter :)